# Why isn't my renderer initialising in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, renderer

Sorry for the lot of code, I don't like to put everything in one file and you need to see all the files. Anyway, the problem is that the `init` function in the `Window` class (initialized in SDL.cpp and declared in SDL.hpp), the renderer isn't working? Of course, that means that the images and textures will also not load, but I'm thinking this is all because of the renderer failing. Can you figure out why it's doing this and help me out?

If I haven't explained it very well just let me know, thanks.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "SDL.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    Window window("SDL window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1080, 720, false);

    //Start up SDL and create window
    if (window.init()) 
    {
        if (window.loadMedia())
        {
            bool quit = false;
            SDL_Event e;
            window.image = window.load_surface("Hello_World.bmp");
            while (window.running)
            {
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)// if event SDL_QUIT is added the poll event
                    {
                        window.running = false;// will shutdown the game loop running everything and close the program.
                    }
                }
                //Clear screen
                SDL_RenderClear(window.gRenderer);

                //Render texture to screen
                SDL_RenderCopy(window.gRenderer, window.gTexture, NULL, NULL);

                //Update screen
                SDL_RenderPresent(window.gRenderer);

                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window.gWindow);
            }
        }
    }

    window.close();

    return 0;
}
```

SDL.hpp

```
#include <SDL.h>

class Window {
public:
    Window(const char* title_, int xpos_, int ypos_, int width_, int height_, bool fullscreen_);
    //Starts up SDL and creates window
    bool init();

    //Loads media
    bool loadMedia();

    //loads an image/texture(to the) surface
    SDL_Surface* load_surface(std::string path);
    SDL_Texture* load_texture(std::string path);

    // renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    //Frees media and shuts down SDL
    void close();

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* gWindow = nullptr;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = nullptr;

    //The window renderer
    SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

    //Current displayed texture
    SDL_Texture* gTexture = NULL;
    
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Surface* image = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* image1 = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* image2 = nullptr;
    int imageNum = 1;
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    const char* title;
    bool fullscreen;
};
```

SDL.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.hpp"
#include <SDL.h>

Window::Window(const char* title_, int xpos_, int ypos_, int width_, int height_, bool fullscreen_) {
    title = title_;
    xpos = xpos_;
    ypos = ypos_;
    width = width_;
    height = height_;
    fullscreen = fullscreen_;
}
bool Window::init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;
    int flags = 0;
    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (fullscreen) {
            flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if (gWindow == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (gRenderer == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "renderer failed to init" << std::endl;
            }
            //Initialize renderer color
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );                
        }
    }

    return success;
}
SDL_Surface* Window::load_surface(std::string path)
{
    //The final optimized image
    SDL_Surface* optimizedSurface = nullptr;

    SDL_Surface* loadSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
    if (loadSurface == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n" << path.c_str() << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Convert surface to screen format
        optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(loadSurface, gScreenSurface->format, 0);
        if (optimizedSurface == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to optimize image %s! SDL Error: %s\n" << path.c_str() << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }

        //Get rid of old loaded surface
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadSurface);
    }
    return optimizedSurface;
}

SDL_Texture* Window::load_texture(std::string path)
{
    //The final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    //Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n" << path.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create texture from surface pixels
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
        if (newTexture == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n" << path.c_str() << std::endl;
        }

        //Get rid of old loaded surface
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    }

    return newTexture;
}

bool Window::loadMedia()
{
    bool success = true;
    gTexture = load_texture("Hello_World.bmp");
    if (gTexture == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture image!\n" << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void Window::close()
{
    //Free loaded image
    SDL_DestroyTexture(gTexture);
    gTexture = NULL;

    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what errors you are getting, or explain what is not working exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: You have a typo: ` renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);` should be ` gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);`

Comment: You have two `SDL_Renderer*` members. (Why do some of your member variables have a "g" prefix? Did you rewrite this from using globals and add more members by mistake?)

Comment: I wondered why it wasn't working LOL that explains it, thanks for helping me out

Comment: Also there is a g I front of the sdl  objects because that's the way laby foo did it and I'm following along, I guess it stands for graphics or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SDL.hpp contains two `SDL_Renderer*` members: `renderer` and `gRenderer`. Remove the former and update this line in SDL.cpp to use the latter:

   ```
   gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
   ```
2. In the function `Window::load_surface(..)` there is a call to `SDL_ConvertSurface` which uses `gScreenSurface` which is still a null pointer. First, obtain the surface from the window:

   ```
   gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
   ```
3. The code should now run, but the bitmap may flash in the window or not appear at all. This is because the render loop in the `main` function tries to update the window as fast as possible. To make a stable image appear, let the program wait for a key press right after the `SDL_RenderPresent` call, or have the thread sleep there.

All error checking in code snippets omitted for brevity.